# Codeigniter unable to using Ajax-json_encode when using models query

Tags: mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I'm new in CodeIgniter, I have a problem using AJAX to update my MySQL-DB field. The AJAX code didn't update the database, and of course, it did not give the `success` attribute (I'm confused about the name) using `json_encode`. 
I've tried so many times, and when I didn't use the models -I moved the query to be executed directly in the controller- and it worked fine, the database was updated. But I thought it is a bad idea.

Here's my Controller's function:

```
public function applicant_is_present(){
    $data = array(
             'idplm'=>$this->input->post('idplm')
            );

    $this->applicant_model->give_attendance($data);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}
```

Here's my model function:

```
function give_attendance($applicant){
    $query = 'UPDATE apptable SET khdrp = \'present\' WHERE idplm = '.$applicant->idplm.' ';
    $this->db->query($query);   
}
```

Here's my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.css"); ?>" />
<html>
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"); ?>"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/bootstrap.js"); ?>"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   function attends(id){

     var url;

     url = "<?php echo site_url('applicant/applicant_is_present')?>";

     $.ajax({
         url : url,
         type: "POST",
         data: {idplm: id},
         dataType: "JSON",
         success: function(data){

           if(data.status){
             jQuery("div#beginning_response").show();
           }else{
             for (var i = 0; i < data.inputerror.length; i++){
                $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').parent().parent().addClass('has-error'); $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').next().text(data.error_string[i]); 
           }
         }

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('Error adding / update data');
      }
    });
 }
 </script> 
 </head>
 <body>
      .
      . 
       //some codes to print $that_applicant object
      .
      .
     <div id = "beginning_response" style='display: none'>
            Present!
     </div>
     Applicant's Presence : 
            //this is the button to call the script
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" title="update" onclick="attends('<?php echo $that_applicant->idplm; ?>')">Present</a>
            <br/>
            <br/>
```

Comment: try without `$this->applicant_model->give_attendance($data);` this line and check if u getting ajax succss.

Comment: yes, I got the ajax success, but without the line, how do I update the database?

Comment: You have error your code.You should turn on error to see what error you getting.You sending `$data` as array to `give_attendance` function but you using it as object `$applicant->idplm`. It is giving you error. Use it as `$applicant['idplm']`

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the JSON data sent in the Ajax request in your controller like this:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

This will get the raw data sent in the request. You can then use json_decode to convert to a PHP array.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use built in codeigniter update method, so your script will be like this

```
$res = $this->db->update('apptable', array('khdrp' => 'present'), array('idplm' => $applicant['idplm']));
return $res; /* return boolean data */
```

Then you can use this script on your controller

```
if($this->applicant_model->give_attendance($data)){
    echo '{"status": "success"}';
}
```

Comment: Still facing the same problem :/